# Why do things show up on the wrong page in scribus? Is this bad?

Tags: page-layout, scribus

I'm used to blender stack exchange so tell me if I'm doing anything wrong.

I have a two-fold spread for a yearbook I'm making. My template page looks like this image:

[image: What two pages is supposed to look like]

But when I add a new page and import page one from that file it looks like this image:

[image: Items from wrong page appear on the side]

It appears that some items are assigned to the wrong page somehow even though I had the right page selected when I created the items. I have three small questions about this:

1. Why does this happen?
2. Can I fix it?
3. Will it print correctly if I can't fix it?

I have researched this problem but haven't gotten any results.

Thanks in advance.

**Update: Here is the file on google drive:**

[Google Drive Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1v_XAvwpAKCKnAf2KQBrk4tRfwYFTG7rH?usp=sharing)

I'm sure you guys already know, but you have to download the entire 'CPYearbookTemplate' folder that has all the files inside it.

Comment: Don't use Scribus so no answer, but for a spread view (in western cultures) page 1 is always a single page (that is, half the horizontal size of a spread) on the right side. All odd numbered pages are right-side. The space to the left of page 1 is the art board.

Comment: Are you saying I need to add another page at the beginning? As a cover page? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: I am saying that your template is for an "even+odd" page spread (i.e. pages 2-3). It is unclear to me from your screenshots, but it looks like you placed the template on page 1 and that the "even half" is off the page and on the artboard (i.e. does not print). Alternatively, the "even half" is on the page, the "odd half" is on the artboard, and your document is set to "single page" rather than "facing pages" or "spreads." Note that anything on the artboard, but outside the page bounds is either not going to print or will be what is called "bleed."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your screenshot and description it's not really clear to me what exactly your are doing.

If what we see is your real template, I fear that you're doing it a bit in a funky way...

Templates are something a bit special in Scribus and I would only suggest experienced users to create them (not because it's hard, but because they probably know when it's worth creating (and maintaining) a template)

Personally, I never create templates, but i tend to open and reuse old files. Feels a little dirty, but it's pretty simple to do.

Anyway, I gave it a try, created a double sided file with two shapes, one per page, saved it as a template and created a new file based on it: the new document did have two pages and had the expected shapes in there. At the right place.

If you can share the file, I can have a closer look at it...

If I can give you a further hint: don't use grids in Scribus... just use the guides.
And instead of dealing with templates, you might want to have a look at the master pages...

---

Updated after having seen the template file.

Indeed, Scribus cannot import correctly your pages.

The reason is that you have created the items on the first page and moved them (slowly?) to the right page. Scribus has a hard time finding out that the items are now completely on a different page.

If you want to be on the safe side, it's better to move the items by cutting them on the original page and pasting them on the new one.

Currently, you can fix your template by:

- clicking on each item that show up on the wrong page
- cutting it
- pasting it

The item should not move.

Finally, would you mind uploading your document to http://bugs.scribus.net ?
This is an issue I'd like the Scribus team to look at...
(I can upload it for you, if it's too much hassle...)

Comment: Okay, so I call it a template just because it has the fonts, colors and graphics that we need for the yearbook, but it is not actually saved as a template. I just collected it for output and saved it as a folder of files. So we're gonna reuse it like you said. Also does the grid mess things up if I use it? Because I use it to put a .25 in. space between items. Hold on and I'll share the file. :)

Comment: I uploaded the file. If you add another page and then import page 1 from 'template.sla' then that's what goes wrong.

Comment: The grid does not mess things up, but it's not really a good tool for aligning items, when doing layout (as opposed to vector graphics, where it fits much better!) It's just that you will have a hard time aligning your frames and getting a good layout. For aligning things you will probably want guides and typographic grids ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_(graphic_design) ).

Comment: Since you now have updated your question with the template file, I am going to update my reply.

Comment: YES! Cutting and pasting works! Although it depends on what page is selected when it is cut. If left page is selected when items from the right page are cut, then when you select the right page and paste it, it looks like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_FzWCcQ87QjWEvyXkcg-GaqfPmCNg1MF/view?usp=sharing Maybe that's a clue. Anyways, if I can make sure that the correct page is selected both when cutting and when pasting, I should be good. Thank you so much! Let me see if I can post the file to the bug page. . . :)

Comment: P.S. The color boxes from the image were locked, so they got copied, but not cut, so that's not an error. :) In case you were wondering.

Comment: Actually can you add the file to the bug page? I don't know how to do it and I don't have time to figure it out.

Comment: I made it on linux 1.4.6 on debian linux if any of that matters. Tell me if you need more information. :)

Comment: Hi @DaDudeII, I did one more quick test and i came to the conclusion that the bug is fixed in the development version (1.5.x). I've tried to recreate a simpler template, where the items would then be imported on the wrong page: that seems not to be possible anymore.  Indeed, I think to recall that a bug has been fixed in the past, where the owning page was not changed, when moving an item with the arrow keys. If you give more details on how you came up with items on the right page that are "still" on the left page I can try if it's really fixed. Until then, you will have to copy paste...

Comment: Okay. I guessed that it might be fixed in a more recent version. I got the most recent version there was for linux. As for how I created items, I had the correct page selected, I clicked on the image, text, or shape buttons to draw frames that snapped to the margins. Seems like the normal procedure to me. Perhaps it was a problem with snapping to the margins. Cutting and pasting isn't much of a hassle, so I don't mind the extra step at all.